# sqlalchemy unknown database flask with multiple databases

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I created two databases using flask and sqlalchemy. My code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\dmac\\testmac.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
   'User': 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\dmac\\User.db',
   'Stock': 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\dmac\\Stock.db'
}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db, render_as_batch = True)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   manager.run()

class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
  __table_name__ = 'users'
  __bind_key__ = 'User'
  __table_args__ = {'schema': 'User'}
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(100))

class Stock(db.Model):
  __table_name__ = 'stock'
  __bind_key__ = 'Stock'
  __table_args__ = 'Stock'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  prices = db.Column(db.Float)
```

I tried to perform the flask-sqlalchemy upgrade after doing the migrate and init --multidb to fill my databases with table. However, I got the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:(sqlite3.OperationalError) Unknown database "USER"[SQL:'\Create Table "User.users (id INTEGER not NULL, name VARCHAR(100))](Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Any help would be appreciative. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but could you try naming you table names all in lowercase:
`user` and `stock`?

Comment: I have tried it. It did not work.